# nginx location index directive not working

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx and I just can't determine why my nginx config doesn't work as expected. All I want to do is to make nginx prioritize index.html over index.php for every web root (/) request.

This is my nginx config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    server {
        location / {
            index   index.html index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  localhost:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
                          $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include       fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 32K;

    client_max_body_size 300M;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ----------------- cut ---------------

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Where's my error? What's the correct way to write this nginx config?

Comment: I believe if your virtual hosts define a different index it would give the priority to the virtual host file not the one in the `http` block, let's say this is a default option unless defined elsewhere.

Comment: there's no more config on the virtual hosts

Comment: I can't get it to behave as you describe, I have set up a test config in the cloud almost identical to your description, and yet still it prioritizes the .html correctly.  Couple questions: 1) what does "nginx -v" say?  2) Have you tried commenting out your virtual host config lines?  3) I hate to ask this question, but you did restart the nginx process, after you modified the nginx.conf, correct?  4) Have you tried eliminating any possible browser issue by using wget or curl to attempt the same connection?     I'm on nginx/1.2.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Convention:

You should keep location and server declarations in virtual host files (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`, as you can see from the nginx conf). Files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` are typically symlinked to files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in order to become "enabled"

### Some things to try

See my [blog post](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-12-04-lemp-nginx-setup) here which has a setup similar to yours.

Try moving your `index index.html index.html index.php` files directive outside of a `location {}` block

Answer (score 9):

If you explicitly request /index.html, is it served? If not, you might want to add an explicit `root /path/to/root;` to your `server {}` block. Also verify that index.html has the correct permissions.

This will help with troubleshooting: It will force a 404 if the root index.html is not found. If that happens, at least you can check the logs to see were it was looking:

```
location = / {
  index   index.html;
}
```

Also, be sure to do `nginx -s reload` when changing the config.

Comment: `index` not working in the `location` block, it must be defined in the `server` block

Comment: @AndreyIzman According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html `index` works in following contexts: `http`, `server`, `location`