# Forbidden homepage via Apache/Nginx

Tags: apache, docker, nginx

HI I am using  nginx and apache (docker per each)

Problem:  when i open the site.com . i got forbidden error , and the webpage(based on php) working only if I open the following URL:
/index.php . or /index . and then all other pages working as it should

```
nginx conf:

events {
  worker_connections 4096;
}
http {
  client_max_body_size 150m;
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://site:8080/;
    }
}
```

apache -vhosts conf

DocumentRoot /var/www/site

```
<Directory /var/www/site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I tried to put this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

in htacess file but it is not working

Comment: is your Directory index setup to default to index.php? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343451/nginx-location-index-directive-not-working

Comment: @Liquidchrome . hi , where ?

Comment: If you are proxy-ing to http://site:8080/, then that server should have directory index set to index.php. For apache in httpd.conf, <IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php </IfModule dir_module>. For nginx, location / {index   index.php;}

Comment: @Liquidchrome . Hi where do I put it in apache.conf  ?  can i put it everywhere ?

Comment: anywhere after the document root and directory setting

Comment: hi still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used like this on a local server and it loads the proper index php on doc path.
Also, try this without your rewrite rule. It could be overriding this setting.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/site"
<Directory "/var/www/site">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in apache-vhosts.conf : 'siter'

```
<Directory /var/www/siter>
```

When you intended /var/www/site